# Is there any way to load the Vuforia dataset in Unity streaming assets folder on demand or separately to reduce the main apk size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, object-tracking

I am developing an AR application in Unity using Vuforia's model tracking. So I generated a model target using the Model Target Generator, exported it and imported the unity package file in my Unity project. I imported the .dat file in the Streaming Assets folder in Unity Assets.
The problem is the apk size has increased a lot due to this file. As the streaming assets directory is read only, is there any other way to load the .dat file on demand? The apk size might become too big, if the dataset size are increased in future.

Addressables and apk expansion file method did not help.

Comment: If I remember correctly unfortunately Vuforia was kinda hard coded on using Streaming Assets .. but maybe that changed by now ... Have you tried [this](https://library.vuforia.com/objects/model-targets-api-overview#create-a-model-target-observer)?

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible and there are recommendations documented in the library of Vuforia Engine: https://library.vuforia.com/unity-extension/building-large-vuforia-engine-apps-unity/.